# Identify prior 1930's US Battleship and US Navy plane

Tags: military, ships

Looking to identify this battleship--USS Nevada, Pennsylvania, Arizona?

Comment: Are you going to include a picture?

Comment: Yes, thought it went with the post. I will have to send a new one (first time on this site).